# 80% learn English and 50% French. What percentage learns German?

Tags: combinatorics

Each of the 20 students learns exactly two out of three languages: English, French, and German. 80% learn English and 50% French. What percentage learns German?

A- student speaks English P(A)=0.8, P(A')=0.2
F- student speaks French P(F)=0.5, P(F')=0.5

I do not know how to deal with this. I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each student learns $2$ languages, the percentage of German, French, and English learned should total $200\%$ together.

Therefore, $70\%$ learn German.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why total is 200%?

Comment: think about it like this; if each student learned 1 language, then it would be 20 "languages" learned by 20 students for a total of 100%, but now it's 40 "languages" learned by 20 students for a total of 200%

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks again.